# if statement only works if step though quickly

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am trying to incorporate a page system in my app. With these pages, I want buttons to appear or disappear depending on what page the user is currently on. With the method I am currently using, only the very first if statement works properly. If I were to press the next button slowly all the way to the end, the condition fails. However, If I were to rapidly press the next button, it works just fine. Same thing if I wanted to go back to current page == 0. If I slowly press, it fails. If I were to rapidly press it success.

How my logic looks is as follows.

```
 struct Pages {
    let imageName: String
    let headerText: String
    let bodyText: String
    
}

  let pages1 = [
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text"),
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text"),
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text"),
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text"),
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text"),
    Pages(imageName: "image", headerText: "header text", bodyText: "body text.")
]

 func setUpPageControlShouldNotShow() {
        if self.PageControl.currentPage == 0 {
            previousButton.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            previousButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else if PageControl.currentPage < 5 {
            TakeALookButton.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            TakeALookButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else if PageControl.currentPage == 5 {
            nextButton.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            nextButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

And I am calling this function inside of cellForItemAt which looks like.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    setUpPageControlShouldNotShow()
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let page = pages1[indexPath.item]
    cell.page1 = page
    return cell
}

  lazy var PageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pc = UIPageControl()
    pc.currentPage = 0
    pc.numberOfPages = pages1.count
    pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = GREEN_Theme
    pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 207/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1)
    return pc
}()
```

// updated this is how my current page is being changed.

```
   @objc private func handleNext() {
    let nextIndex = min(PageControl.currentPage + 1, pages1.count - 1)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: nextIndex, section: 0)
    PageControl.currentPage = nextIndex
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    
}
```

am I calling in the right place? Ive tried to use less logic, but it does not function properly from the start. This was the closest I've gotten to function properly.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to call your function in `cellForItemAt`; this function can be called numerous times and for various index paths. If the buttons should be changed as a result of a page control changing, change them when the page control changes.  Also there seems to be a lot of repeated code in that function; it could probably be refactored to simply things; create  `enable` and `disable` functions that accept a UiButton as an argument and set the properties

Comment: where are the page controls current page get changed?

Comment: @VikasSaini I have updated my question to show how my page control is being changed. pages1 is a index of 6 different Pages